# My standard search and frontend categories are broken!

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, catalog, ajax, search

The Magento multi-store site I was building for my work was very nearly complete when I went to search for a product and it didn't work. Not only did it not work but the footer disappeared on the search page aswell, so I've done all of the normal stuff (re-indexing, flushing cache, Apache error logs and the magento logs) the only error i could find was this one:

"[Fri Mar 10 12:34:46.426260 2017] [:error] [pid 1719] [client 192.168.0.9:50662] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Activo_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext::getFoundData() in /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext/Collection.php on line 148, referer: http://new.va-technologies.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=asus"

I then begin disabling extensions until the search looked relatively normal again (i.e. the footer came back) the extension responsible was "VE Ajax Cart & Filters".

When this is disabled the search still doesn't work, as in nothing is displayed other than the breadcrumbs. But the footer is there. Also when it is disabled the categories no longer show products like they used to they are the same as the search pages.

The advanced search works throughout all changes.

I then decided to uninstall the plugin, clear cache all that stuff all over again. The search then goes back to how it originally was with the extension activated and the categories were all showing products again.

So i install another Ajax cart to see if it makes any difference, it doesn't.

I reinstall the original "VE Ajax Cart & Filters" extension. And the cycle continues no matter what I try I can't get the search to work properly at all and cant get the categories to show products and for the search page to look right at the same time. I have tried multiple themes and the issue is across all 3 sites, all using different themes.

**EDIT:**
I also just found this error code:

"[access_compat:error] [pid 30423] [client 192.168.0.131:52914] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/new/public_html/app/etc/local.xml"

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the majority of themes which you can buy on the market are coming with some extensions which are tightly coupled with the theme itself, so it's high chance to get into troubles if you install any extension which conflicts with existing functionality. To solve such kind of issue, you'll have to be experienced developer and to know the Magento damn well.

There is no silver bullet. You can try every combination of extensions you can get, and still no one guarantee that they will work in combination. I guess Activo_CatalogSearch extension, and extension related to ajax cart & filters are touching the same classes on intrusive way, and that's why they cannot work together.

Comment: I guessed that was the case but its the fact that even when the extensions are all disabled and with a blank standard theme. It still doesn't work. Also thanks for replying so quickly.